# Subtracting powers with variable in exponent

Tags: exponential-function

I am having some troubles with a question that subtracts powers.

Solve for unknown:
$$3^{x+4} - 5(3^x) = 684$$

I have a hunch that I should apply factorization somehow. Do I multiply 5 and 3 to begin or should I change to logarithm form and have the 5 act as an exponent on $3^x$, and then factorize?

Any recommendations are appreciated!

Comment: You can't multiply the 5 and 3 because of pemdas. Exponentiation to x comes before multiplication. To proceed, realize that 3^x and 5(3^x) are like terms. Combine them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited it at the user's notification.

$$3^{x+4}-5(3^x)=684 \implies 3^x\cdot3^4-5(3^x)=684 \implies 3^x(3^4-5)=684 \implies (76)3^x=684 \implies 3^x = \frac{684}{76} \implies 3^x = 9$$

You can take it from here.

Comment: Hey Drew, appreciate your feedback ... I mistakenly did not insert brackets around (x+4) .. so the equation is actually: 3^{x+4} - 5{3^x} = 684  ...  I dont think I can factorize 3^x ?

Comment: Oh, just a sec, I'll update it then.

Comment: Cheers Drew, it helps to simplify what the exponent is actually telling us!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean $3^{x+4}-5(3^x)=684$ or $3^x+4-5(3^x)=684$.  If you mean the first, then rewrite $3^{x+4}$ as $3^x\cdot3^4$ and then factor $3^x$ out.  If you mean the second way, subtract $4$ from each side and then factor out $3^x$.  Hope this helps.

Comment: After I submitted my comment I now see the equation formatted correctly, so I see that you actually meant the second way.

Comment: You get a suspiciously nice value of $x$ when you use the first interpretation , so I would go with that over an imaginary solution, which is what you get if you go with the second one.

Comment: indeed.  How often have many of us ended up with a more difficult problem because we simply read and copied the problem incorrectly?

Comment: @B.H. you are right, it is the first interpretation! I should have used brackets when formatting!!

Answer (score -1):

You factor out the $3^x:$
$(3^4-5)(3^x)=680$
$\longrightarrow$
$76(3^x)=680$
Now, you can solve this equation with calculator.